# nodejs get response from api without refreshing page

Tags: node.js, request

EDIT:
I started nodejs few days ago and i want to understand one thing.
Imagine that i have a nodejs web communicate with API, when i send request (offer for a specific user) i would like to know if user has accepted or declined the offer without refreshing the site. I know there is a way with AJAX, but is there any better solution how can i get state of the offer if it is accepted/declined (if something change)

Every advice is appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the question and the only way anyone could understand how that site works is to study the client-side code from that site which you can do if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: I edited my question hope it is better explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know in the client when the state of something on the server changes (at some indefinite future time), then here are three options:

1. You can regularly "poll" the server every so often with an ajax call asking for any updates on the offer.  The server can then return the current state of the offer and the client can update the status in the current web page.
2. You can create a webSocket or socket.io (socket.io is an API on top of a webSocket) connection from the client to the server.  This is a long lasting connection which allows the server to send data to the client at any time.  So, anytime the server sees a change in the state of that offer, it can send an update to the client and the client can then modify the current page to show that change.
3. You can use the newer server-sent events which is an extension to http which allows a server to send data to a client to accomplish something similar to the previous option.

Comment: thank you so much for the possibilities. What do you think is the best way to do it? I think Ajax is not the best choice or am i wrong?

Comment: @JakubStaněk - It depends upon your particular circumstances.  If you need near real-time notification when the state changes on the server, then options 2 or 3 are best.  If you are interested in server efficiency, then 2 or 3 are best.  If you don't need real-time notification so you can live with polling ajax every few minutes, then the ajax solution might be the simplest to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i have one more question. If i choose second option how can i detect if something on server has changed? because the api is not on my site, and i do not want to call ajax or something to ask for the api again. Can you explain the second option more for me? EDIT: how can server detect if offer state has been changed (without ajax calls)?

Comment: @JakubStaněk - That's an entirely different issue and should be the subject of a whole different question.  In that new question, you have to describe what it is that you're trying to track changes in and what API access you have to it.